Polyglossia with Russian too small math latin letters
Good time of the day!
I am trying to use polyglossia with Russian, but math-mode  letters are too small.
How to make theer size equal to the size of the cyrillic  letters?
Here is an example:
 \documentclass[10.5 pt]{extreport}

\usepackage{fontspec} 

\usepackage{fouriernc}

% PACKAGES FROM AMS
\usepackage{  amsthm, amssymb,latexsym,amsfonts}

\usepackage[reqno,fleqn]{amsmath}


\usepackage{mathtools}



%-------------------
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Arial}
    \setotherlanguage{english}


\begin{document}
\paragraph{Определения и обозначения.}
\begin{itemize} 
\item Простой граф это граф у которого нет параллельных ребер и петель. 
\item $k$-дольный граф - это граф, множество вершин которого может быть разбито на $k$
подмножеств так, что ни одно ребро ни в одном подмножестве не имеет обоих концов.
%---
\item  Полный $k$-дольный граф - это простой граф, в котором каждая вершина
соединена с каждой вершиной, не входящей в одно и то же подмножество. 
%---
\item Полный  $m$-дольный граф с $n$ вершинами, в котором каждая часть имеет либо $[n/m]$, либо $\{n/m\}$ вершин, обозначается через $T_{m,n}$.
%--
\item $[x]$ - наибольшее целое число меньшее или равное $x$.
\item $\{x\}$ - наименьшее  целое число большее  или равное $x$. 
\item $\nu(G)$ - число вершин графа $G$.
\item $\epsilon(G)$ - число ребер графа $G$.
\end{itemize}
\paragraph{Вопрос.}
Покажите, что 
\begin{align*}
    \epsilon(T_{m,n})=\binom{n-k}{2}+(m-1)\binom{k+1}{2},\quad \text{где}\:\:\:
    k= [n/m]. 
\end{align*}


\end{document}


There might be a better way, but with Arial I would use  \newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Arial}[Scale=.85] and \documentclass[11pt]{article}  Check that it matches the $x. Also I would use Arial Unicode MS or Charis SIL.  Please also make your MWE complete starting with documentclass{} etc, makes it easier for people to provide you with solutions.

Thanks  yannisl. This worked.
